# Find out what is causing a memory leak in a application

Tags: linux, memory

I have a Linux (CentOS) server on which I run a game server on which recently started leaking memory after an update. How can I find out what is causing the memory leak in the server?

Comment: The answer to your question may be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143791/how-do-i-find-which-process-is-leaking-memory

Comment: try valgrind to see the leak and identify it.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory profiling**
Use Perf tool to check the leaks.

***Run the last command for all the processes running in the application and tally the results to find out what is causing memory leak.***

A sample usage of probes with perf could be to check libc's malloc() and free() calls:

> $ perf probe -x /lib64/libc.so.6 malloc
>
> $ perf probe -x /lib64/libc.so.6 free

Added new event:
probe_libc:malloc (on 0x7eac0)

A probe has been created. Now, let's record the global usage of malloc and free across all the system during 4 second:

> $ perf record -e probe_libc:malloc -agR sleep 4
>
> $ perf record -e probe_libc:free -agR sleep 4

Let's record the usage of malloc and free across all any process during 4 second:

> $ perf stat -e probe_libc:free -e probe_libc:malloc -ag -p $(pgrep $process_name$) sleep 4

Output:

> Performance counter stats for process id '1153':
>
> 11,312 probe_libc:free
>
> 11,644 probe_libc:malloc
>
> 4.001091828 seconds time elapsed

If there is increase in difference between malloc and free count for every time perf command is run, it is a hint of memory leak.

> $ perf record -e probe_libc:free -e probe_libc:malloc -agR sleep 2

Run the above command to check for the whole application.

Later run,

> $ perf report

to get the report of the above run.